# How can I access a device connected through MacOS Internet Sharing?

Tags: macos, network, internet-sharing

I have an Allen and Heath Qu-32 soundboard which has the ability to be controlled from a mobile device on the same network. Where it is currently, I can’t plug the board directly into the router, so instead I have attempted to connect it to the local network through MacOS’ Internet Sharing feature. I have an iMac connected to the router through WiFi, and with Internet Sharing, I have the soundboard connected through an Ethernet cable from the iMac. The soundboard says it has an IP Address of “192.168.1.2”, however, when I attempt to connect to this address from a phone on the WiFi network, it does not work. Networking is not my forte, but I suspect that Network Sharing creates its own sub-network of some sort. Is it even possible to connect to this device, and, if so, how?

P.S.- As I mentioned, Networking is not my forte so you may have to dumb it down for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By visiting Allen and Heath's website, one can determine the manufacturer assumes a wireless router with at least one LAN ethernet jack would be available for use with the Qu-32 soundboard.

> *The idea proposed in the posted question of simply substituting the iMac's macOS Internet Sharing for the wireless router does not work because a different LAN is created for each chosen physical port. Also, the iMac's WiFi can only be assigned to one LAN at a time*

For example, if a second WiFi adaptor (as a physical port) was add to the iMac, then by employing macOS Internet Sharing, the iMac's ethernet physical port and the wireless access point provided by the second WiFi adaptor would exist on different LANs.

Using the existing wireless access point may be possible provided which TCP/IP ports to forward in the iMac can be determined and that the chosen ports would not conflict with ports needed by the iMac for proper functioning of the iMac. There have already been answered questions explaining how to instruct a Mac to port forward. Below are two such questions. Unfortunately, the answers probably are not as dumbed down as much as requested.

- This question address newer versions of OS X and macOS: [Redirect traffic using PF along with Internet Sharing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100492/redirect-traffic-using-pf-along-with-internet-sharing).
- This question addresses older versions of OS X: [Port Forwarding From a Shared Connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156847/port-forwarding-from-a-shared-connection).

A simple solution would be to acquire a wireless router with at least one LAN ethernet port, as shown in the [Qu Series Reference Guide](https://www.allen-heath.com/media/Qu-Mixer-Reference-Guide-AP9372_10.pdf). In this case, the only reason to use the iMac's macOS Internet Sharing is to allow devices in the same LAN as the Qu-32 soundboard access to the rest of the internet. Below are two modification to the instructions given in the [Qu Series Reference Guide](https://www.allen-heath.com/media/Qu-Mixer-Reference-Guide-AP9372_10.pdf) that would allow such devices access to the internet.

- Turn on the router functions, such as DHCP, in the wireless router and use the wireless router as a router, wireless access point and ethernet switch. The iMac would be connected to the WAN ethernet jack on the router. All remaining ethernet connections would be to the LAN jacks in the router. Here, the router functions, such as DHCP, would be supplied by both the iMac and wireless router. There would be two LANs. The first LAN would be between the iMac and the wireless router and the second would be between the wireless router and the other devices.
- Turn off the router functions, such as DHCP, in the wireless router and just use the wireless router as a wireless access point and ethernet switch. All ethernet connections (including the iMac) would be to the LAN jacks in the router. Here, the router functions such as DHCP would be supplied by the iMac. This configuration allows the iMac to exist in the same LAN as the Qu-32 soundboard.

### Other References

[General. Qu. SQ. Sending CC MIDI messages from an app over TCP/IP to control QU/SQ](https://support.allen-heath.com/hc/en-gb/articles/4411155610641-General-Qu-SQ-Sending-CC-MIDI-messages-from-an-app-over-TCP-IP-to-control-QU-SQ)
[Share MIDI information over a network in Audio MIDI Setup on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/audio-midi-setup/ams1012/3.5/mac/12.0)
[TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944)
[Qu-32 38 IN /28 OUT Digital Mixer](https://www.allen-heath.com/qu-series/qu-32/)
[Qu CHROME EDITION Getting Started Guide](https://www.allen-heath.com/media/Qu-Mixer-Getting-Started-Guide-AP10025_2-V1.9.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I will follow those articles this week and see if I can get it to work. If not I will just end up buying a cheap router to use as an LAN.